# AWS architecture for dynamic web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, web-hosting

I'm designing the architecture of a web server with some dynamically generated html pages and hosted in Amazon AWS.

Obviously, I can do from scratch: create some AWS EC2 virtual machines and install on them a server (apache/tomcat, ...) and the related war files, solve the load balancing and high-availability, ... .

However, as alternative, for an AWS integrated architecture ("server-less"), it seems I need:

a) to distribute the static content (css, js, ...):

- AWS CloudFront (provides https)
- AWS S3 (file storage)

b) to handle dynamic GET/POST calls:

- AWS Api Gateway
- AWS lambda or AWS beanstalk

c) DNS and certificates:

- AWS Route53
- AWS ACM

There are no way to simplify this architecture ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a serverless webapplication from scratch can be a daunting task as you describe.
To simplify this, people use infrastructure as code and frameworks, such as the Serverless framework.

You can find some examples here: https://github.com/serverless/examples